Directional derivatives and differentiability almost everywhere
Suppose that $U\subseteq{\Bbb R}^n$ is open and $f:U\rightarrow{\Bbb R}$ has directional derivatives at every point in $U$ and in all directions. Must $f$ be differentiable almost everywhere?
There are standard examples in advanced calculus for functions with directional derivatives in all directions that are not differentiable at a single point. But these examples are usually differentiable at all other points.
By adding shifted versions of the standard examples, it is easy to get failure of differentiability at finitely many points. So  the question is at how many points can failure occur?
If the directional derivatives are continuous around some point, so are the partial derivatives, and then the function is differentiable, so an example of 'bad' behavior would require at least that the directional derivatives in the direction of a spanning set of vectors not be continuous at the 'bad' set of points.
I specifically ask about getting non-differentiability almost everywhere (so, except for a set of measure zero), but the question is also interesting for co-meager sets.
